# What namespace is CCiModuleCache in for the latest release of Gallio?

Tags: gallio, resolve

I have some old code I'm trying to compile with the class CciModuleCache being instantiated in the code.  It doesn't resolve with the latest version of Gallio.  I still get the red curly underlines under this class.  Does anyone know what namespace this class resides in now?

http://www.gallio.org/

namespace/library I thought it was in, but is not:
using Gallio.Common.Reflection.Impl;

Answer: This class was recently changed so code outside of the assembly can call into it.  It will no longer have an access type of "internal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is now declared as a `public` class for a better reusability. Please try out the next v3.3 daily build in http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables. See also [issue 852](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=852).

**EDIT**: It should be OK in build [v3.3.409](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables) and later.

Answer (score 0):

This class has an access type of internal, so only the Gallio library can access it.